# Electron function window all closed cant see other function

Tags: node.js, electron

Hi I write listen server on port 3000:

```
  const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    // my server function...
  });
  server.listen(3000);
```

In my Electron-vue application I have button to close:

```
<li @click="closeApp">Close App</li>
data() {
    return {
        w: remote.getCurrentWindow()
    }
},
methods: {
    closeApp(){
        this.w.close();
    }
}
```

In main process I have:

```
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    server.close();
    app.quit();
  }
})
```

When I click "Close App" button Electron return error:

> server is not defined

How I can close server and Electron ?

Comment: Please share the ```main``` process file

Comment: is the first snippet in the same script as the main process snippet? is it at the global scope?